# Android regular expression to get first possibility

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching

Hi I am using following code to get the double value from string.

```
if (content!=null){
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
            if(m.find()){
                textView2.setText(m.group(0));
            }
        }
```

But my problem is,it always shows the last occurrence of double value.For example I am having a string "34.56 is greater than 24.67".In this I want to return 34.56,but the above code always return 24.67. Can any one show me the right way to get the first occurrence. Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: you are using `$` which marks end of string..use this `[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?`

Comment: `$` is the end-of-string anchor. That is why the pattern finds the double at the end of the string.

Comment: thanks to both of you it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$`. It's for the end of the string. So it should be:

```
[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?
```